# vb.net registry - get rid of full path from childnodes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, treeview, registry

This is probably a noob question, it is quite late here anyways, but i want to fix this small thing tonight. The problem is that TreeView gives full paths for every single registrykey.

For example: **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Colors** which is annoying if there is a lot of childnodes... It should give **Control Panel -> Desktop -> Colors** like the original RegEdit does.

```
' Recursive method which creates nodes and all child nodes for vParentNode
Private Function CreateNodes(ByVal vParentNode As TreeNode, ByVal vRegKey As RegistryKey) As TreeNode
    For Each vSubKeyName As String In vRegKey.GetSubKeyNames()
        Try
            ' Open subkey and create a childnode with subkeys name on it
            ' Then create childnodes for childnode
            Dim vSubKey As RegistryKey = vRegKey.OpenSubKey(vSubKeyName, False, Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.ReadKey)
            Dim vChildNode As New TreeNode(vSubKey.Name)
            vChildNode = CreateNodes(vChildNode, vSubKey)
            vParentNode.Nodes.Add(vChildNode)
        Catch ex As SecurityException
            ' Lots of security exceptions will be thrown if user is not admin or doesnt have access for whole registry
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next
    Return vParentNode
End Function

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case ComboBox1.Text
        Case "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"
            ' Get registrykey for CurrentUser
            Dim vRegKeyCurrentUser As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser
            ' Create TreeNode and get its child nodes in CreateNodes method
            Dim vParentNode As New TreeNode(vRegKeyCurrentUser.Name)
            vParentNode = CreateNodes(vParentNode, vRegKeyCurrentUser)
            ' Show the nodes on treeview
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(vParentNode)
End Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Dim vChildNode As New TreeNode(vSubKey.Name.Split("\"C).Last())
```

or without Linq:

```
Dim PathElements as string() = vSubKey.Name.Split("\"C)
Dim vChildNode As New TreeNode(PathElements(PathElements.Length-1))
```

Comment: Could work, but right now it gives an error: Expression expected at Split **(** '\\')

Comment: Sorry.  Try `"\"C` instead of `'\\'`.

Comment: The last error is gone now, but a new one has come up: 'Last' is not a member of 'System.Array'. (vSubKey.Name.Split("\"C).Last())   Using Framework 2.0 FYI.

Comment: Not having Linq complicates things slightly.  I've added another solution to the answer that should work for you.

Comment: strange =(.. it says: Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey' at PathElements(PathElements.Length - 1)

Comment: Sorry.  I was working with the wrong line. Try the code in my corrected answer.

Comment: This code works to an extent, it takes out the annoying repetition, but now it just shows the first folder name: for example Control Panel, i cant open it further to get to the other folders/registry keys inside of Control Panel.

Comment: Have you tried running in the debugger?  It's possible you're swallowing exceptions that would give you the answer.  It's probably worth accepting this question as answered, and then asking another question specifically about the tree population problem.